# QScriptEngine queue slot connection

Tags: c++, qt

I'm looking at using QScriptEngine in a project as a simple way to interact with a console application. With a few lines I was able to get everything wired up and it works great (I'm able to call slots on my objects, access properties, etc) except it seems that whenever I invoke a slot through a script command, it is called on the thread that QScriptEngine is on instead of the thread that the QObject is on. I have 3 threads in my application and the slots on the QObjects must be called on their respective threads. Is there a simple way to tell the script engine to fire the slot into the QObjects' threads' event loop?

Comment: maybe emit a signal to the other thread?